# px.choropleth_mapbox now showing map graph

Tags: dictionary, graph, plotly, mapbox

I'm practicing drawing map graphs using the Plotly express choropleth_mapbox.
But the result is only showing the legend bar, not showing any graphs.

My data is simple, population by state. And I downloaded the geojson file from Github.

The followings are the code.

```
import json
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('uspopbystate.csv')
geojson = json.load(open('us2.json'))

print(geojson)

{'type': 'FeatureCollection', 'features': [{'type': 'Feature', 'id': '01', 'properties': {'name': 'Alabama', 'density': 94.65}, 'geometry': {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[[-87.359296, 35.00118], [-85.606675, 34.984749], [-85.431413, 34.124869], [-85.184951, 32.859696], [-85.069935, 32.580372], [-84.960397, 32.421541], [-85.004212, 32.322956], [-84.889196, 32.262709], [-85.058981, 32.13674], [-85.053504, 32.01077], [-85.141136, 31.840985], [-85.042551, 31.539753], 

df.rename(columns={"state": "name"}, inplace=True)

print(df.head())

         name  population
0     Alabama     5024279
1      Alaska      733391
2     Arizona     7151502
3    Arkansas     3011524
4  California    39538223

print(df.info())

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 52 entries, 0 to 51
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column      Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------      --------------  ----- 
 0   name        52 non-null     object
 1   population  52 non-null     int64 
dtypes: int64(1), object(1)

fig = px.choropleth_mapbox(df, geojson=geojson, color="population",
                           locations="name", featureidkey="properties.name")
fig.show()
```

[result : only showing legend bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7U6n.jpg)

Comment: I tried your code looking for similar data. First I got an error because the mapbox style was not set, so I added 'carto-position'. Also the center view is not set so the intended location is not displayed. This is not related to the error, but the column names in the data frame can be handled by using `locations='state'` without changing the state.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. After changing the column name, did it work?

Comment: If you change the column name, the map will still be displayed.